# Android - TextView text is hidden under button

Tags: android

I have a TextView text and it is hidden under button and not wrapped before button. It looks like text is ignoring button and wrapping at the end of line. How to wrap the text before button?

This is how it looks like now:
[image: Hidden text under button]

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context="com.test.TestActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Status"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wifi_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/wifi_text"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/wifi_text"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_wifi" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wifi_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Wi-Fi: some longer text should be on two lines and it is not on two lines"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/status_text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/wifi_settings_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Set"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/wifi_text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/wifi_text" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

How to wrap text before Set button?

Comment: Trry to change last line in Button widget from `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/wifi_text"` to `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/wifi_text"`

Comment: wifi text has no constraints on the right side (end) to the button. Set a constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context="com.test.TestActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Status"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wifi_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/status_text"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_wifi" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wifi_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Wi-Fi: some longer text should be on two lines and it is not on two lines"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/wifi_icon"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/wifi_settings_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/status_text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/wifi_settings_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Set"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/status_text" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Result:

[image]

Explanation: attached `ImageView` to parent's left side:

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
```

attached `Button` to parent's right side:

```
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
```

after that we attached `TextView` to `ImageView's` right side and `Button's` left side, then set `layout_width` to `0dp` to fill all available space between `TextView` and `Button`:

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/wifi_icon"
app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/wifi_settings_button"
android:layout_width="0dp"
```